# Proof that the solutions are algebraic functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ideals, differential-algebra

I am looking at the following:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

$$$$

---

$$$$

I haven't really understood the proof...

Why do we consider the differential equation $y'=P(x)y$ ?

Why does the sentence:  "If $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$, then $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has also a solution $y_{\mathfrak{p}}$ in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$." stand?

Also why do we put $\displaystyle{y_{\mathfrak{p}}=\prod_i (x-\overline{\alpha}_i)^{c_i}}$ ?

$$$$

**EDIT1:**

I found now the following sentence:

The constant field of the differential field $k((x))$ is $k((x^p))$. 
Hence if $(1)_p$ has a solution in $k((x))$, multiplication by a suitable constant yields a solution in $k[[x]]$.

Do we maybe have the following?

We suppose that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$. 
The constant field of $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ is $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x^p)$. 
So if we multiply the equation by a suitable constant, it follows that $(3)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has a solution also in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$.

$$$$

**EDIT2:**

Could you explain to me how exactly we conclude that $\beta_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Why do we consider $y'=P(x)y$ ? It should be related to $(1)$ for $n=1$, i.e., to Grothendiek's problem.

Comment: But why do we consider that the coefficient of $y'$ is $1$ ? @DietrichBurde

Comment: I understood now why we take this differential equation... @DietrichBurde But I still don't understand why it stands that if the equation has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}(x)$ then it also has a solution in $\overline{K}_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$...

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you take a look at it? @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 8):

> Why does the sentence: "If $(3)_\mathfrak p$ has a solution $y_\mathfrak p$ in $\overline K_\mathfrak p(x)$, then $(3)_\mathfrak p$  has also a solution $\tilde y_\mathfrak p$ in $\overline K_\mathfrak p[x]$." stand?

Assume there is a rational solution, which could always be written $y_\mathfrak p = \prod_i(x-\alpha_i)^{c_i}$ for some $c_i \in \mathbb Z\setminus 0$.

Assume that $\overline K_\mathfrak p$ has characteristic $p > 0$ (i.e. $p\in\mathfrak p$). The equation $(D-Q)y = 0$ is linear, and the solutions form a module over $\overline{K}_\mathfrak p[x^p]$ just because $D(x^p) = 0$. Then for all $n > 0$, the elements $(x-\alpha_i)^{p^n} = x^{p^n} - \alpha_i^{p^n}$ are in $\overline{K}_p[x^p]$, so you can obtain a new solution $\tilde y_p$ just by clearing the denominators of $y_p$, i.e. by taking

$$\tilde y_\mathfrak p =\prod_i (x-\alpha_i)^{p^{n_i}}$$ where $n_i$ are chosen so that $p^{n_i} \geq -c_i$.

Note: I haven't said anything about what happens when $\mathfrak p$ does not have a residue field of positive characteristic.

ADDED:

> Explanation for $\beta \in \mathbb Q$.

He uses ($\star$) to conclude that $\beta \in \mathbb Q$. The way one should use ($\star$)  is to take the number field in ($\star$) to be $\mathbb Q(\beta)$, so that the conclusion of ($\star$) is $\mathbb Q(\beta) = \mathbb Q$, i.e. $\beta \in \mathbb Q$. So, we just need to see why almost all primes in $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ are of degree one. Let's call $F := \mathbb Q(\beta)$

Having already passed to a suitable extension field such that $\beta \in K$, there is an inclusion $F \hookrightarrow K$. Also, from Honda's proof it is known that $\beta$ is a rational integer modulo $\mathfrak p_K$ for all but finitely many primes of $K$.

Denote $\mathfrak p_F := F \cap \mathfrak p_K$ the prime of $F$ lying under $\mathfrak p_K$. Since the map $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p_F \to \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p_K$ preserves $\beta$ (i.e. sends $\beta +\mathfrak p_F \mapsto \beta + \mathfrak p_K$), then $\beta$ is also a rational integer modulo $\mathfrak p_F$ (nothing special happening here: morphisms of fields are always injective, the preimage of an integer is an integer, etc.).

We have just checked that $\beta$ is a rational integer modulo $\mathfrak p$ for almost all primes $\mathfrak p \subseteq \mathcal O_F$. (The only primes for which $\beta$ is not a rational integer are the ones lying under the finitely many primes in $K$ from above.)

All that remains is to ask: if $\beta$ is a rational integer modulo $\mathfrak p_F$, then why must $\mathfrak p_F$ have degree one? Basically this is just because every element $a \in F$ (in particular, every element of $\mathcal O_F$) can be written as a sum $$a = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\beta^i,$$ which, modulo $\mathfrak p_F$, becomes a sum of rational integers. So $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p_F$ is equal to its ring of rational integers, i.e. is degree one.

ADDED: (miscellaneous questions)

> could you explain to me what a residue field is?

We start with $\mathfrak p$ a prime in $K$ - this actually means a prime ideal in the ring of algebraic integers $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq K$. To get the residue field, first localize $(\mathcal O_K)_\mathfrak p$ so that $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p \subseteq (\mathcal O_K)_\mathfrak p$ is now a *maximal* ideal, then quotient by $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p$ to get a field. This is what is usually called the residue field. It looks like Honda is then taking the algebraic closure of this.

For example, maybe your number field is trivial, i.e. just $\mathbb Q$, then the ring of integers is $\mathbb Z$; your prime might be $(p)$ for some prime number $p$. Then the residue field is $\mathbb Z_{(p)}/(p)_{(p)} \cong \mathbb F_p$.

Or maybe your number field is $\mathbb Q(i)$, with algebraic integers $\mathbb Z[i]$. It has primes of degree $1$ like $\mathfrak p = (1+i)$ with residue field $\mathbb Z[x]/(x+1, x^2 +1) = \mathbb Z[x]/(x+1, 2) \cong \mathbb F_2$, $\mathfrak p = (2+i)$ with residue field $\mathbb F_5$, and primes of degree 2 like $\mathfrak p = 0$ with residue field $\mathbb Q(i)$ and $\mathfrak p = (3)$ with residue field $\mathbb Z[i]/3 = \mathbb F_3(i) \cong \mathbb F_9$.

> Why can a rational solution be written $y_\mathfrak p= \prod_i (x−\alpha_i)^{c_i}$ for some $c_i\in \mathbb Z\setminus 0$?

There's no real content here, just because we have passed to the algebraic closure $\overline{K}_p$ the polynomials split into products of linear factors.

> What does the equation $(D−Q)y=0$ represent?

I mistakenly called the rational function $P$ from the problem $Q$ instead. If the original equation is $y' = Qy$, and $D$ denotes the differentiation operator, then the equation is $Dy = Qy$, or $(D-Q)y = 0$.

> What does it mean that the solutions form a module over $\overline K_\mathfrak p[x^p]$?

It just means that (1) if $y_1, y_2$ are both solutions to $(D-Q)y = 0$, then so are $y_1 \pm y_2$ (the solutions form an abelian group), and (2) if $y_1$ is a solution, then $y_2 := x^py_1$ is also going to be a solution. (This is because $D(x^py) = x^pD(y)$.) This implies that given any $f \in \overline K_\mathfrak p$ and solution $y_1$, $y_2 := f\cdot y_1$ is also a solution.

Comment: First of all, could you explain to me ehat a residue field is? $$$$ Why can a rational solution be written $y_p = \prod_i(x-\alpha_i)^{c_i}$ for some $c_i \in \mathbb Z\setminus 0$ ? What does the equation $(D-Q)y = 0$ represent? $$$$ What does it mean that the solutions form a module over $\overline{K}_p[x^p]$ ?

Comment: Sure, I'll just edit the answer.

Comment: I am looking again at the part where you explain what a residue field is. $$$$ Is an algebraic integer an integer that is a root of a monic polynomial? $$$$ Could you explain to me further the sentence: "To get the residue field, first localize $(\mathcal O_K)_\mathfrak p$ so that $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p \subseteq (\mathcal O_K)_\mathfrak p$ is now a *maximal* ideal, then quotient by $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p$ to get a field." ? What do you mean by $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p$ ?

Comment: $\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}$ is just the ideal of $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ generated by $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Ok... What do you mean by "localize $(\mathcal O_K)_\mathfrak p$" and what by "quotient by $\mathfrak p_\mathfrak p$" ?

Comment: By "localize $(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p}$" I meant "take the localization $(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p}$ of $\mathcal O_K$ at $\mathfrak p$".

Comment: Then $\mathfrak p_{\mathfrak p}$ is a maximal ideal in $(\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p}$, which you quotient by to get the residue field $k(\mathfrak p) := (\mathcal O_K)_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Ahaa... Ok... I have it think about to see if I have understood that. $$$$ Could you maybe explain to me at the proof how we conclude that $\beta_i  \in \mathbb{Q}$  ?

Comment: OK I think I have explained this in the new edit, let me know if there are any concerns.

Comment: At Fact 2, at the part "All rings of integers of number fields are finitely generated as rings. This means that there are finitely many primes lying over a given prime. " why does the first sentence mean the second one?

Comment: $F=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is the agebraic number field of $(\star)$, right? Do we take $L=K(\beta)$ because of the following part of the proof? "...in some suitable extension field of $K$ we have $P(x)=\sum_i \frac{\beta_i}{x-\alpha_i}$..."

Comment: The first question is answered in the link following that sentence. The reason I used $L$ was because we needed to use $F$ in ($\star$), but we only knew hypotheses about $K$. In order to relate the two fields it seemed useful to take an extension containing both.

Comment: And is this extension the suitable one to have $P(x)=\sum_I \frac{\beta}{x-\alpha_I}$ ? Or isn't this related to that?

Comment: I guess that extension would be $K(\alpha_I,\beta_I)$.

Comment: Ahaa... OK... So would it be then $$\alpha_i\equiv \overline{\alpha}_i\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}\\ \beta_i\equiv c_i\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$$ ?

Comment: Yeah I think so.

Comment: I am looking again at the beginning, at the part: $$$$ "the solutions form a module over $\overline{K}_\mathfrak p[x^p]$ just because $D(x^p) = 0$. Then for all $n > 0$, the elements $(x-\alpha_i)^{p^n} = x^{p^n} - \alpha_i^{p^n}$ are in $\overline{K}_p[x^p]$". $$$$ Knowing that the solutions form a module over $\overline{K}_\mathfrak p[x^p]$  why does it imply that $(x-\alpha_i)^{p^n} = x^{p^n} - \alpha_i^{p^n}$ are in $\overline{K}_p[x^p]$ ?

Comment: Well it is clear by definition that the right hand side $x^{p^n} - \alpha_i^{p^n}$ is in $\overline{K}_p[x^p]$. As for the equation, this is just the so-called [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream#Prime_characteristic).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32971/discussion-between-ben-dyer-and-mary-star).

Comment: I understood it now!! :-) Could you explain to me why at the last part of the proof $y$ is an algebraic function?

Comment: That's just because rational exponents are interpreted as roots, e.g. if $\beta = 3/2$ then $(x-\alpha)^{3/2} = \sqrt{(x-\alpha)^3}$ is an algebraic function.

Comment: Why does this stand? Why are rational exponents interpreted as roots? I haven't understood it..

Comment: Well $x^{1/n} = \sqrt[n]{x}$ because $(x^{1/n})^n = x^1 = x$.

Comment: So, does it always stand that when we have an expression that is raised up to a fractional power then it is an algebraic function?

Comment: As long as that expression is a polynomial, yes.

Comment: Ok... I see... $$$$ At the beginning you said that a rational solution is $y_\mathfrak p= \prod_i (x−\alpha_i)^{c_i}$ for some $c_i\in \mathbb Z\setminus 0$ because we have passed to the algebraic closure. But when $c<0$ the expression is not a polynomial, is it? Can then still every element be splitted into linear factors?

Comment: A rational function is just a ratio of polynomials, each of which may be split into linear factors. The ones in the denominator you give negative powers.